# Como centralizar um form verticalmente e horizontalmente com responsividade utilizando o bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formulário, login, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá! Por favor,preciso de ajuda/orientação. Sou iniciante e estou criando um login com bootstrap e gostaria de centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente esse form.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="POST" name="formulario" class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 ">
      <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 26rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Entrar na sua Conta</div>
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">E-mail</span>
            </div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" required>
          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Senha</span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user-password" placeholder="Digite sua senha" required>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-md-6 offset-md-3 " id="enter-button">Entrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-md-6 offset-md-3 " id="google-button">Login com
              Google</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-6 offset-md-3 " id="facebook-button">Login com
              Facebook</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn col-md-6 offset-md-3 btn-link" id="register-button">Não tem conta?
              Cadastre-se </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 ou boostrap 3 ?

Comment: A parece que as divs estão incompletas

Answer (score -1):

Você deve utilizar as classes `align-items-center`, para alinhar verticalmente, e `justify-content-center` para alinhar horizontalmente, no sua div que possui a classe `row`.

Vai ficar mais ou menos algo como:

```html
<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form>
            ...
        </form>
    </div>    
</div>
```